# how to update the excel formula calculate result ，I use apache poi 5.2.2

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

```
File f = new File("/data/test.xlsx");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/data/test.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
wb.write(os);
os.close();
```

but it doesn't work,when i open my excel,it still notice that do I need to save the excel file,it means that the formula doesn't update ,how to fix this issue?

Comment: when i run this coe,it throws the exception:Could not resolve external workbook name 'XXXXX',but i don't know where  the workbook is,can i ignore the exception to calculate the result of formula?

Comment: Rather than commenting, please [edit] your question to add new details. Why not loop through the cells manually to see what formulas _can_ be evaluated?